# Python sort nested dictionaries by value descending

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary something looks like this

```
{
'Host-A': {'requests': 
    {'GET /index.php/dashboard HTTP/1.0': {'code': '200', 'hit_count': 3},
     'GET /index.php/cronjob HTTP/1.0': {'code': '200', 'hit_count': 4},
     'GET /index.php/setup HTTP/1.0': {'code': '200', 'hit_count': 2}},
'total_hit_count': 9},
}
```

as you can see for `'Host-A'` the value is a dict contains requests received and hits count on each page.. the question is how to sort the `'requests'` in descending order. so then I can get the top requests .

example of correct solution output would be like:

```
{
'Host-A': {'requests':
    {'GET /index.php/cronjob HTTP/1.0': {'code': '200', 'hit_count': 4},
     'GET /index.php/dashboard HTTP/1.0': {'code': '200', 'hit_count': 3},
     'GET /index.php/setup HTTP/1.0': {'code': '200', 'hit_count': 2}},
'total_hit_count': 9},
}
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: python dictionaries are key-value pairs and are not sorted in any way. You can use `OrderedDict` if you want though: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

Comment: @Gassa I have modified the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python 3.7+, where the order of dict keys are preserved, and given your dict stored in variable `d`, you can sort the items of the `d['Host-A']['requests']` sub-dict with a key function that returns the `hit_count` value of the sub-dict in the second item of the given tuple, and then pass the resulting sorted sequence of items to the `dict` constructor to build a new sorted dict:

```
d['Host-A']['requests'] = dict(sorted(d['Host-A']['requests'].items(), key=lambda t: t[1]['hit_count'], reverse=True))
```